# It is safe to use $mysqli->insert_id for assign topic to post in a forum script?

Tags: php, mysqli

I've a forum script that makes for every new topic a "container" and assign to it each post linked to the topic.

So, when I open a new topic my script makes a new row in `forum_topics` and a new row in `forum_posts`.

In `forum_posts` it put into `parent` column the `id` of the *topic container*.

For know who is the container of the post I'm creating I use:

```
$mysqli->insert_id
```

I'd like to know if it is safe, I think to two users who open a new topic at the same time... It is a plausible problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes it is safe.
Each PHP process uses separate connection and this variable contains inserted id from this very connection